# WinSCP gives a '/tmp' directory error while saving a changed file

Tags: ubuntu, sftp, winscp

Even when I'm logged in as a root user to my remote Ubuntu 22.04 server thru WinSCP 6.1.2, I get this error when I save a changed file (even though I found that the changes made by me are saved in that file, but these errors irritate):

[image]

The contents of the error (also showing partially in the attached screen shot) are:

> Error moving file '/.../web_only.yml' to '/tmp/web_only-20231025-122258.yml'.
>
> General failure (server should provide error description).
> Error code: 4
> Error message from server: Failure
>
> Common reasons for the Error code 4 are:
> - Renaming a file to a name of already existing file.
> - Creating a directory that already exists.
> - Moving a remote file to a different filesystem (HDD).
> - Uploading a file to a full filesystem (HDD).
> - Exceeding a user disk quota.

I've not been able to find the option of *'Moving files to Recycle Bin'* in WinSCP settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have enabled "Recycle bin" feature in WinSCP:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_recycle_bin

So WinSCP tries to move the previous version of the file to a configured recycle bin at `/tmp`. And as possibly the edited file is on a different file system, the move fails.

If you really wanted to use the recycle bin, you need to configure it on the same file system.

If it was a mistake, just turn it off.